# React Semanti UI Corner Icon image and Icon

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

is there any way to have img and Icon Corner Icon using Semantic Ui. so i need to have the img show and add icon to it

```
<span>
<i class="huge icons">
  <img src="test.jpg"></img>
  <i class="corner add icon"></i>
</i>
<span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using `semantic-ui-react`.
You can do:

```
<Icon.Group size='huge'>
  <img src="test.jpg" />
  <Icon corner name='add' />
</Icon.Group>
```

You can find more examples [HERE](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon#icon-example-loading-group)